# jQuery UI tabs positioned about 50% of their height below eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, google-cdn

This is quite odd, and I can't get it to stop happening.

Here's the relevant code. I'm using a Google CDN host for the UI-lightness theme.

```
<div id="prof_div">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#prof_home">Profile</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#prof_details">Details</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#prof_settings">Settings</a></li><br/>
    </ul>
```

That's the only relevant HTML. Here's jQuery/JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#prof_div').tabs({ 
            fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' } 
        });
    });
```

And it's displaying like this:

```
TAB 1
      TAB 2
            TAB 3
```

Instead of like this:

```
TAB 1 - TAB 2 - TAB 3
```

I have no custom CSS acting on them at all (I even blanked my stylesheets to check).

Any idea why this is happening? I'll post a screenshot if necessary.

Thanks! :)

EDIT

Here's my CDN requests

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=very long string"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/JSFunctions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.6.4");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
....
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those ending `<br/>`s from your `<li>`s. They shouldn't be there.

```
<div id="prof_div">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#prof_home">Profile</a></li><br/>
    <li><a href="#prof_details">Details</a></li><br/>
    <li><a href="#prof_settings">Settings</a></li><br/>
</ul>
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cB8zA/1/).

Comment: Ugh, I feel so stupid. I had them there ages ago when I was trying to get it to go vertical, nearly a week ago. Can't beleive I forgot to remove them. Thanks.

Comment: It fixed it. Thanks for the fast response too.